# Expect: Some long delay at the shell prompt after ssh login

Tags: tcl, expect

Running my expect script

```
  set timeout 15
  spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
  expect {
    -re "closed by remote host" { continue }
    -re "(P|p)assword: " { send "$pass\r"; exp_continue }
  }
  expect -re $prompt
  send -- "sudo passwd\r"
  ...
```

always waits at the shell prompt for 10+ seconds before sending the "sudo passwd" command, no matter what timeout value I use.

$      (<-- always waits here for 10+ seconds)

Any tip would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That's usually because a pattern is not getting matched. Run your program with `expect -d scriptname` to see what's happening

Comment: Thanks, Glenn. My other posting is directly relevant to this problem and your answer there seems to be already answering to my problem on this posting. For others, my other posting is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74788485/expect-regexp-to-include-various-shell-prompts?noredirect=1#comment131995142_74788485